# Hide columns in one sheet based on a cell from another sheet - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Inside an excel workbook I have sheet1 and sheet2.

In **Sheet1** I have a cell that changes dynamically (cell A1).
In **Sheet2** I have a cell (B1) that copies the value from cell A1 from Sheet1.
On **Sheet 2** cells will hide when the value in B1 is 0.

[image: link image]

Here is the VBA code from sheet2

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Range("B1").Value = "0" Then
        Columns("E:I").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Else
        Columns("E:I").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If

End Sub
```

The thing is that when I change the value on **Sheet1** nothing happens on **Sheet2**, and I don´t know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code in sheet 1 calculate event,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
   If Range("B1").Value = "0" Then
      Sheet2.Columns("E:I").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
   Else
      Sheet2.Columns("E:I").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
   End If
End Sub
```

and do some calculation in sheet1-B1 cell(say =0+0), if the result is 0 then it will hide the columns E:I in Sheet2.

Comment: You are checking B1 on sheet 1 but B1 is in sheet 2

Comment: Sheet 1 is the default one where the computation happens, based on the computation result in sheet1, sheet2 columns get hided.

Answer (score 0):

Used code on sheet1 to hide columns on sheet2

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Range("A1").Value = "0" Then
        Sheet2.Columns("E:I").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Else
        Sheet2.Columns("E:I").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Worked great. Thanks for the tip vanathaiyan